# Simple python loop error

Tags: python

```
print("Hi im a PC and my name is Micro, What's your name?")
name = raw_input("")
print("Hi " + name + " how are you, are you good?")
answer = (raw_input(""))
if answer == "yes":
           print("That's good to hear!")
elif answer == "no":
           print("Oh well")
while answer != ("yes","no")
           print("Sorry, you didnt answer the question properly, Please answer with a yes or no.")
print"I'm going to sleep for 5 seconds and then i'll be back."
import time
time.sleep(5)
print"I'm back!"
```

need to create a loop for the yes or no bit, anyone know how?
thanks for any help!

Comment: It's okey to be new at something. But may I suggest you look thru these serie of videos: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKTZoB2Vjuk&ob=av3e or something similar? That will take you a few hours but it will be totally worth it. You will get some basic understanding of how things work :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `while True:` and when you want to stop the loop use `break`.

This would be your code than:

```
...
while True:
    answer = (raw_input(""))
    if answer == "yes":
        print("That's good to hear!")
        break
    elif answer == "no":    
        print("Oh well")
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry, you didnt answer the question properly, Please answer with a yes or no.")
...
```

Comment: sorry im really new and although iv heard of both of these i havent yet learnt them. would you care to explain or give an example

Answer (score 1):

And now for a completely different thing:

```
options = {'intro':"Hi, I'm a PC and my name is Micro, What's your name? > ",
           'ask':  "Hi %s how are you, are you good? > ",
           'yes':  "That's good to hear!",
           'no':   "Oh well",
           'error':"Sorry, you didnt answer the question properly\n",
           'hint': "Please answer with yes/no"}

name = raw_input(options['intro'])

while True:
    try:
        answer = raw_input(options['ask'] % name)
        print options[answer.lower()]
        break
    except KeyError:
        print options['error'], options['hint']
```

As you said you are a noob in Python, I wanted to introduce here several new things to complement the other answer you may find useful.